# Can wood be "dyed" transparent?

Tags: finishing, staining, coloring

Is it possible to "dye" or otherwise treat wood so that is becomes transparent? Or at least, somewhat permits light to pass?

I think I've seen examples of very thin handplane shavings which have a similar 'diaphanous' effect but I'm thinking of a treatment which could be applied to thicker pieces (though not necessarily very thick).

Answer (score 7):

Apparently there is at least one method of doing this, by chemically breaking down or replacing wood lignin with acrylic.

However this method may only be practical in laboratory-type settings, or at least its not like there is an obvious readily-available product to do it. But it could be with some more digging that a practical process could be described. So I thought it was at least worth posting an answer.

Source: [Transparent wood can store and release heat](https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/pressroom/newsreleases/2019/april/transparent-wood-can-store-and-release-heat-video.html)

> ...scientists report a new kind of transparent wood that ... transmits
>   light
>
> Three years ago, lead investigator Lars Berglund, Ph.D., and
>   colleagues at KTH Royal Institute of Technology in Stockholm, Sweden,
>   reported an *optically transparent wood* in the ACS journal
>   [Biomacromolecules](https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/pressroom/presspacs/2016/acs-presspac-march-30-2016/transparent-wood-could-one-day-help-brighten-homes-and-buildings.html). **The researchers made the material by
>   removing a light-absorbing component called lignin from the cell walls
>   of balsa wood. To reduce light scattering, they incorporated acrylic
>   into the porous wood scaffold.** The team could see through the
>   material...

There is a [video link](https://youtu.be/ks7gZXQJczI?t=14) in the source. Here is an example of one of the steps in altering the balsa wood:

[image]

And the results of a later stage:

[image]

Interestingly this research seems oriented towards the use of wood as a construction material, but nonetheless might have some knock-on uses in other areas, maybe even fine woodworking.